# mySQL: Select first number not in subquery results

Tags: mysql, sql, string, subquery, where-clause

I have a column `itemId` that contains unique IDs in the format US001, US002, US003 etc.
The trailing numbers of these IDs are not consecutive as rows may have been deleted.

I am looking for a way to **find the first number that DOES NOT EXIST** in my column.

**Example 1:**
Column: US001, US002, US004, US006.
**Expected result: 3**.
**Example 2:**
Column: US001, US002, US003, US004, US007.
**Expected result: 5**.
**Example 3:**
Column: US001, US002, US003, US004, US005.
**Expected result: 6**.

I tried the following but this returns NULL or no results (also no error):

```
SELECT MIN((RIGHT(i.itemId, 3)) + 1) AS nextAvailableId
FROM items i 
WHERE RIGHT(i.itemId, 3) NOT IN 
(
    SELECT * FROM 
    (
        SELECT RIGHT(i2.itemId, 3) AS itemNo 
        FROM items i2 
    ) AS x 
)
```

Can anyone please help me with this ?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using window functions and string functions:

```
select min(id) + 1 as nextAvailableId
from (
    select substr(itemid, 2) as id, 
        lead(substr(itemid, 2)) over(order by substr(itemid, 2)) as lead_id
    from mytable t
) t
where lead_id > id + 1 or lead_id is null
```

In MySQL 5.x, where string functions are not available, you can use a subquery:

```
select min(substr(itemid, 2)) + 1 as nextAvailableId
from mytable
where not exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where substr(t1.itemid, 2) = substr(t.itemid, 2) + 1
)
```

Comment: This works perfect. Thanks a lot for the quick reply ! :) I personally find the second option more logical but is the first one to be preferred performance wise ?

Comment: One small thing I noticed: This does not seem to work if the first ID (US001) is missing in my column and the expected result should be 1. Is there a way to cover this here too ?